# Redireccionar cuando hago login por redes sociales

Tags: laravel, socialite

Cuando ingreso a una ruta protegida con el el middleware `auth`, este me direcciona a la página de login y una vez logueado, me redirecciona a la página que solicitó el login.

He implementado un sistema de login con redes sociales y quisiera replicar este comportamiento cuando inicie sesión por este medio.

No se me ocurre como hacerlo, ahorita por defecto me está direccionando a la página de inicio.

Este es mi código de login por redes sociales:

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider)
{

    //Verifica si se ha rechazado la solicitud
    if(! $request->has('code') || $request->has('denied') ){
        return redirect('login');
    }

    //Almacena en una variable los datos devueltos por la red social
    $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    //Recuperando nombre de usuario
    if($socialUser->name){
        $name = $socialUser->name;
    }else{
        $name = $socialUser->nickname;
    }

    //Recuperando email de usuario
    $email = $socialUser->email;

    //Verifica si existe un usuario registrado con ese correo, de no ser así, se crea uno
    $check = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if($check){
        $user = $check;
    }else{
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email
        ]);
    }

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect('/');

}
```

Comment: ¿Probaste `return redirect()->intended('/');` en vez de `return redirect('/');`?

Comment: Excelente, funcionó, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Está apenas nombrado en el documentación, en el apartado **Authentication** [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users):

> El método `intended` en el redirector redirigirá al usuario a la URL a la que intentaba acceder antes de ser interceptado por el middleware de autenticación. Se puede proporcionar un URI alternativo a este método en caso de que el destino previsto no esté disponible.

Entonces, puedes simplemente cambiar el return de tu función de `return redirect('/');` a:

```
return redirect()->intended('/');
```